# What explains the "saw teeth" shape of the pending transactions graph?

Tags: txpool

The graph of pending Ethereum transaction does not seem to show a flat line, rather, it looks like "saw teeth" with the number of pending transactions rising slowly for an hour or so and then dropping off sharpy within a minute. What explains this phenomenon?

https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx

It is also visible here: https://txpool.zengo.com/#0,24h